# plots in matploblib become noisy

Tags: python, linux, numpy, matplotlib

so my code are :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
x1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y1 = [1, 4, 9, 14, 25]
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
s2 = np.sin(4*np.pi*t)

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplots(211)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.subplots(212)
plt.plot(x1, y1)

plt.figure(2)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(t, s1)
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(t, 2*s1)

plt.show()
```

when I just run fig 2 it's all okay but when I run all the code, plots become noisy
also instead of 2 fig it will run an empty fig as fig num1
as u can see the result in pic1
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DMhV.png)

Answer (score 2):

You have a small typo inside your code.
In the plots belonging to `figure(1)` change your `subplots()` to `subplot()` (remove the trailing s)

Comment: This does solve the original problem but for me (Spyder 4, Python 3.7) the second plot still has issues. I wonder if its a problem with Spyder though.

Comment: @DrBwts I tested it with Spyder 4.1.4 and Python 3.7 aswell (freshly installed it, because normally I use another IDE) and I have no issues with these plots. Neither in inline plotting (plots pane) nor in Qt (popup plots)